# Transactions in SpringBoot + SpringDataJPA don't work

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa

I have Spring service. This service get exsiting order from db and assign to it user given as an argument. When order id is equal to 4, then the transaction should be rolled back. Unfortunately, it isn't happening. RuntimeException is thrown, but changes are saved in database.

This is my configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TransactionsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Service:

```
@Transactional
void reconnect(Order o, User u) {
    o.setUser(u);
    orderRepository.save(o);

    if (o.getId() == 4L) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Transaction should be aborted.");
    }

}
```

I call this method from REST Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/reconnect/{id}")
public Order reconnect(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Order order = orderRepository.findOne(id);
    User user = userRepository.findOne(2L);
    mainService.reconnect(order, user);

    return order;
}
```

Comment: And from where are you calling this method? From another transactional method which includes a try/catch?

Comment: You don't need `@EnableTransactionManagement` and your `reconnect` method needs to be public.

Comment: It works! Thank you.